# Need help restricting a js function(that restricts invalid chars) to a particular input type

Tags: javascript

Hi i would like to restrict a function that allows only, numbers, back space and left & right arrow keys to inputs with number type, because when i implement it, it also affects my text inputs.

```
<script>
    function chars(evt){
        var key = window.event ? event.keyCode : event.which;
        if (event.keyCode == 8 || event.keyCode == 46
            || event.keyCode == 37 || event.keyCode == 39) {
            return true;
        }
        else if ( key < 48 || key > 57 ) {
            return false;
        }
        else return true;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: How are you invoking your function?

Comment: this way onkeypress="(return chars(event))" . it works but it affects all inputs

Comment: Your parameter is `evt` but you're using `event`

Comment: if i change that would it affect inputs with number type only

Comment: @IkechukwuKalu if you only want it to affect number-type `input` elements, why are you using it on anything which isn't a number-type in the first place?

Comment: i'm quite new to java script... i really don't know how. So that's why i'm asking

Comment: i'm invoking it on my form tag? because the input i require it for, already has an onchange attribute. i'm not sure if that would work?

Comment: check inside the function if the element that trigger the `onkeypress="(return chars(event))"` event correspond to your only numeric inputs... [this may help](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events)

Comment: thanks i manually invoked my function on each input number type.That solved it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assign an **id** to your `<input>`. Add an [event listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) to it, like :

```js
function getKeyCode() {
    var key = window.event ? event.keyCode : event.which;
    if(event.keyCode == 8 || event.keyCode == 46
        || event.keyCode == 37 || event.keyCode == 39) {
        console.log(true);
     //return true;
    } else if (key < 48 || key > 57) {
        console.log(false);
        // return false;
    } else {
     console.log(true);
     // return true;
    }
}

var el = document.getElementById("myInput");
el.addEventListener("keypress", getKeyCode);
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myInput">
```